# JQuery vars outside JS file

Tags: php, jquery

In a header file i have which is populated by PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var packages = {};
packages[1] = {title:'Pack 1',price:7.50,setup:0.00,template:0};
packages[2] = {title:'Pack 2',price:12.00,setup:0.00,template:0};
packages[3] = {title:'Pack 3',price:25.00,setup:75.00,template:1};
var templates = {};
templates[4] = {title:'Template 1'};
templates[5] = {title:'Template 2'};
templates[6] = {title:'Template 3'};
</script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/jscript/form.inc.js"></script>
```

Now in the form.inc.js i want the content of the vars packages. So like:

```
function updatePrices(){
    var package_price = 0;
    var setup_price = 0;

    var package = $_2('#package_select').val();

    package_price += packages[package].price;
    setup_price += packages[package].setup;

    $_2(".package_price").html("&pound;"+package_price);
    $_2(".setup_price").html("&pound;"+setup_price);
    $_2(".total_price").html("&pound;"+(package_price+setup_price));
}
```

You see here: packages[package].price that packages[1].price and should show 7.50, but i dont think the var packages is being passed though!

Any help would be awesome thanks

Comment: Do you have a page we could actually try? As you describe it, this should work. Perhaps `updatePrices()` is being called before the script that defines `packages` is being run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script isn't being run because it has a syntax error in it:

```
var packages = {};
packages[1] = {title:'Book'In',price:7.50,setup:0.00,template:0};
/intake/:21SyntaxError: Parse error
packages[2] = {title:'Book'In Plus',price:12.00,setup:0.00,template:0};
packages[3] = {title:'Full Monty',price:25.00,setup:75.00,template:1};
var templates = {};
templates[4] = {title:'Template 1'};
templates[5] = {title:'Template 2'};
templates[6] = {title:'Template 3'};
```

Notice that you're using single quotes to mark the title strings, but two of the titles have single quotes in them. You need to escape the single quotes with a slash, like so:

```
packages[1] = {title: 'Book\'In',price:7.50,setup:0.00,template:0};
```

Please look at your browser's JavaScript/Error Console. It'll do wonders for you =D

Comment: Thank you! I just changed the single quotes to double quotes and it works fine! packages[1] = {title: "Book'In",price:7.50,setup:0.00,template:0};

Comment: In general you should be careful about this, especially if you're generating this stuff programmatically. Ideally you should use something that can generate JSON or at the very least escape quotes for you.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your packages and templates vars are objects, i think you wanted an array:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var packages = [];  //square brackets instead of curly brackets create new arrays

packages[1] = {title:'Pack 1',price:7.50,setup:0.00,template:0};
packages[2] = {title:'Pack 2',price:12.00,setup:0.00,template:0};
packages[3] = {title:'Pack 3',price:25.00,setup:75.00,template:1};

var templates = []; //square brackets instead of curly brackets create new arrays

templates[4] = {title:'Template 1'};
templates[5] = {title:'Template 2'};
templates[6] = {title:'Template 3'};
</script>
```

Comment: While he probably should be using arrays, this isn't why it's failing. You can use numbers as indexes of objects just fine.